# annoying "feature" (or bugs?) for RODBC

Tags: r, import, odbc, xls, rodbc

RODBC is the main library in R to import data from a database into R. `RODBC` seems to have the ability of "guess" the datatype of the column which I find it particularly annoying.

I have uploaded a file `test.xls` [here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/m144px), or you may create a xls file yourself:

1. create 2 columns, first column named `col_a` and the second column named `col_b`.
2. type whatever you like in `col_a`, I typed letters on this column for 92 rows
3. at the 92th row of col_b, type a number there, I typed "1923" without changing the data type (i.e. not using `'`)
4. try to import the xls file into R using the following script:

---

```
library(RODBC)

setwd("C:/Users/hke775/Documents/Enoch/MISC/R_problems/RODBC")
channel <- odbcConnectExcel("test.xls",readOnly=TRUE)
dummy.df <- sqlFetch(channel,"Sheet1")
odbcClose(channel)
```

---

You will see that in `dummy.df`, `col_b` is all `NA`, the `1923` in this column is gone.

If you want to see the `1923` again, you can change the 1st row of `col_b` to a number, and it is back again.

This is very annoying as I don't prefer modifying data manually. I need to use other package to do the xls importing, but I can't find other packages do as smooth as `RODBC` (I tried `gdata` and `xlsReadWrite`).

Did I missing anything in the `sqlFetch` command, and cause the trouble? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you tried gdata?  When I tried your test file with the gdata package using `DF <- read.xls("test.xls")` it worked.  The `1923` was present.

Comment: Gdata needs to have perl, which I can't install it in my office

Comment: If the powers that be can install R then they should also install the Rtools distribution too since that is required for R development and that has perl in it: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: so my issue is considered to be a bug for `RODBC`?

Comment: It might be a problem with the ODBC driver rather than RODBC itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please don't blame R or RODBC for [Microsoft's bugs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)... ;)

> However, due to a bug in the ODBC driver, specifying the Rows to Scan
>   (MaxScanRows) setting currently has no effect. In other words, the
>   Excel ODBC driver (MDAC 2.1 and later) always scans the first 8 rows
>   in the specified data source in order to determine each column's
>   datatype.
>
> For additional information about the Rows to Scan bug, including a
>   simple workaround, click the article number below to view the article
>   in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> [189897](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189897/EN-US/) XL97: Data
>   Truncated to 255 Characters with Excel ODBC Driver

I tried the fix in [KB189897](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189897/EN-US) by setting the `TypeGuessRows` value to 0 and look what happens!

```
> library(RODBC)
> channel <- odbcConnectExcel("test.xls",readOnly=TRUE)
> tail(dummy.df <- sqlFetch(channel,"Sheet1"))
   col_a col_b
87     c    NA
88     d    NA
89     e    NA
90     f    NA
91     g    NA
92     h  1923
> odbcClose(channel)
```

Please, no up-votes or check marks... just send cash. :)

Comment: Great. But then should we conclude that a user without admin privileges has no solution ?

Comment: better set TypeGuessRows to 24 or any deep enough setting. But 0 will do an unlimited scan and will will affect peformance. (I'm reading thousands of non structured .xls/.xlsx files)

Comment: @Langeleppel: Yes, setting to 0 will affect performance, but it will guarantee correctness.  Setting to 24 (or any other non-zero value) will only be correct if it is "deep enough" for all future xls/xlsx files read on the affected system.