# How to do data cleaning using R package RODBC

Tags: r, rodbc

I want to clean multiple `.xls` data files using R package `RODBC`. All the .xls files have the same
 format as follows. In the first 13 rows, there are discriptions for the data file (obviously they are character data). Then from the 15 row, there are date data and numeric data which are actually what I need.

I'm trying to read with sqlFetch from RODBC. The data that is returned by sqlFetch is unfortunately not identical to the source data in that the cells filled with the date data and numeric values are not returned properly but all set to . How to correct this error? Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062761/annoying-feature-or-bugs-for-rodbc

Comment: Almost 8 years ago I complained that RODBC only works well with very regular data -- no holes, and the same data type everywhere: Déjà vu:  http://markmail.org/message/jpkezm67pvynppmx.  About a year ago when I had a similar problem (again), I installed ActivePerl and used the read.xls function in the gdata package instead of RODBC.